# Pandas: Python dataframe plot a graph for values within a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am building an application for databases, and i am at part where i want my program to display a graph of column A vs Column B but for limited range of data in column B.

I want to display a graph for violation code vs number whilst the number is between 10 and 100.
With my code below i am able to plot a graph for data that is < 100, but i also want to add >10 and my syntax keeps getting errors as i am unsure how i can do this.

```
GroupB = df[df['Number of Facilities'] < 100]
GroupB.plot(kind="bar", fontsize=4, x='VIOLATION CODE',
                      y='Number of Facilities',)
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Its been answered below, i got all sorts of errors for different versions of my syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GroupB = df[(df['Number of Facilities'] < 100) & (df['Number of Facilities'] > 10)]
```

Parentheses are not optionals if you want to make an "and" operation.